# Python - Post request - error 400 bad request sending json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, post

I'm getting error 400 when I try to send a json data as post request to my local API. If I print the content of (list), I see the correct data, but when I do the post, I got error 400. Any idea about what is wrong?

P.S.: I need to send the data as json or it will fail. Am I'm doing this right?

Below the code which I'm using:

```
import requests
import json
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
}

list = []

with open('sample.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

for x in lines:
    data = {
        "ApplicationName" : "App1",
        "ServerList" : x, 
        "StartDate" : "2020-12-12 12:00:00",
        "EndDate" : "2020-12-12 13:00:00",
        "SourceTool" : "Moon"
        }
    list.append(data)

list1 = json.dumps(list)
print(list1)

x = requests.post("http://my-local-endpoint.com",headers=headers, json=list1, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('my_username','mypassword'))

print(x.status_code)
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
[{"ApplicationName": "App1", "ServerList": "Server1", "StartDate": "2020-12-12 12:00:00", "EndDate": "2020-12-12 13:00:00", "SourceTool": "Moon"}]
Status code:  400 Bad Request
```

If I send the same data on Postman, it works as expected:

```
{    
"ApplicationName":"App1",
"ServerList":"Server1",
"StartDate":"2020-12-12 12:00:00",
"EndDate":"2020-12-12 13:00:00",
"SourceTool":"Moon"
}
```

Comment: No need to do: `list1 = json.dumps(list)` The list will be converted to json when you do `json=list` in the post method. I would recommend renaming `list` to something else because `list` is a keyword.

Comment: I've changed list for listX but issue remains the same.

Comment: it appears that the API does not expect a list. Try this list1 = json.dumps(list[0])

Comment: @rrudnicki Yes, that's right. What you're sending from Python is a list. In Postman it's dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you a lot for your help guys. I'm always get confused about tuples, dictionary and lists on python.

Even doing the change you've mentioned I got an error. What did the trick was change the json=list1 for data=list1 on request.

Here is the piece of code working.

```
list1 = json.dumps(listx[0], indent=1)

x = requests.post("http://my-local-endpoint.com",headers=headers, data=list1, auth=HttpNtlmAuth('my_username','mypassword'))
print("Status code: ", response.status_code, response.reason, list1)
```

Thank you again.